# hide menu when page loads, onclick button show menu, first click show, second click hide, like toggle in angular 4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I am working on navigation default when page loads navigation should be hide. When I click on icon I want to show navigation like toggle. when I mouse out from navigation I should hide navigation. angular 4.0.

```
index.html 
<button class='user_login' (click)='btnResult()'>
  <img src="./assets/menuicon.png" >
</button>

nav.component.html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu" *ngIf="menu">
     <li ><a routerLink="one">one</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="two">two</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="three">three</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="four">four</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="five">five</a></li>
   <li><a routerLink="six">six</a></li>
 </ul>


nav.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
    menu = false;
    constructor() { 
    btnResult(){
    this.menu = true;
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
component.html

    <button (click)="toggle()" id="bt">
    {{buttonName}}
</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="show">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: left;">
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <div><input id="tbname" name="yourname" /></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email Address:</label>
            <div><input name="email" id="email" /></div></div>
        <div>
            <label>Additional Information (optional):</label>
            <div><textarea rows="5" cols="46"></textarea></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>

component.ts

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public show:boolean = false;
  public buttonName:any = 'Show';

  ngOnInit () {  }

  toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;

    // CHANGE THE NAME OF THE BUTTON.
    if(this.show)  
      this.buttonName = "Hide";
    else
      this.buttonName = "Show";
  }
}
```

Comment: > https://www.encodedna.com/angular/how-to-show-hide-or-toggle-elements-in-angular-4.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at event bindings ([Angular Event Bindings](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding---event-)).

Create a function in the component's logic which binds to the element's `mouseleave`:

Template:

```
<ul (mouseleave)="hideMenu()">[...]</ul>
```

Component:

```
mouseleave(): void {
    this.menu = false
}
```

**Update**:

`app-nav.component.html`:

```
<button (click)="showNavigationMenu()">Show</button>
<ul *ngIf="menuVisible" (mouseleave)="hideNavigationMenu()">
    [...]
</ul>
```

`app-nav.component.ts`:

```
menuVisible: boolean

constructor() { this.menuVisible = false }

showNavigationMenu(): void {
    this.menuVisible = true
}

hideNavigationMenu(): void {
    this.menuVisible = false
}
```

Plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GFwwi32eqBveON2qqcXc?p=preview)

Comment: You are binding to the (click) event in the `index.html`, but defining the `btnResult()` logic in the component's template. If you want to interact from a parent component to a child, you should use [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding).

Comment: can u tell me why click event not working what's missing

Comment: can u give me syntax bit of confusion for me

Comment: applied now menu is in hide, after click on button not showing menu, but no error in the console.log

Comment: it's working after moving button in to nav component earlier it was in index.file, but we interact parent to child right

Comment: Yes, in the code I provided in the solution does not interact between the parent and the child component (incidentally here is a [plunker with the solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/GFwwi32eqBveON2qqcXc?p=preview)). It has all the logic contained inside the navigation component as you can see by the `app-nav.component.html` title I gave to the template syntax.

Comment: problem fixed Thank you

Comment: Good to hear! Remember to accept the answer if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The wheel has already been invented!

Google "Bootstrap Collapsing Navbar", and you'll find many ways to make your life simpler with the Bootstrap 3 CSS & jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap menu</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```